# Proxy object not being re-assigned JavaScript

Tags: javascript, proxy

Currently doing some work with Proxies that calls for said Proxy to be stored in an array and then accessed from that Array when a certain function is called. The function in question acts to reassign the value of the object to something entirely different.
I.e:

```
function proxChange(proxies, index, val) {
    proxies[index] = val;
}

var a = new Proxy({}, {//Handler stuff});
var proxies = [];
proxies.push(a);
proxChange(proxies, 0, 2);
```

In theory, `a` should now simply be 2, however, it remains as the original proxy. Interestingly, however, if I assign a value to a property of the proxy i.e: `proxies[index]['prop'] = val`, the property assignment shows when you inspect `a`.

Can anyone understand what is occurring here?

Comment: please add *"Handler stuff"* as well and what you expect with the construction.

Comment: I don't believe "Handler stuff" is relevant as the value re-assigns fine if the reassignment happens immediately after `a` is instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just assign a value to an element of an array.

```js
function proxChange(proxies, index, val) {
    proxies[index] = val;
}

var a = new Proxy({}, {});
var proxies = [];
proxies.push(a);
proxChange(proxies, 0, 2);

console.log(typeof a, a);
console.log(typeof proxies[0], proxies[0]);
```